# Single Dimension array automatically rounds values in retrieval

Tags: vba, excel

The array pulls information from the spreadsheet and does a multiplication resulting in a number with 2 decimal points, when I do a sum or have the code loop and add the values in the array they automatically round. Any Ideas?
[image: Screenshot of values being taken from spreadsheet]

```
Function DisplayWeight(ButtonType)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim WArray() As Double
Dim i, j, k, TotalWeight As Integer

Set ws = Sheets("BillOfLading")

j = 1
    For i = 26 To 51 'pg 1
        If ButtonType = "kg" And ws.Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
            If j = 1 Then
                 ReDim WArray(1)
                 WArray(1) = ws.Cells(i, 1) * ws.Cells(i, 24)
                 ws.Cells(i, 27) = ws.Cells(i, 1) * ws.Cells(i, 24) & " kg"
                 j = j + 1
            Else
                ReDim Preserve WArray(j)
                    WArray(j) = ws.Cells(i, 1) * ws.Cells(i, 24)
                    ws.Cells(i, 27) = ws.Cells(i, 1) * ws.Cells(i, 24) & " kg"
                 j = j + 1

            End If
        Else
            If ButtonType = "lbs" And ws.Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
                If j = 1 Then
                     ReDim WArray(1)
                     WArray(1) = ws.Cells(i, 1) * ws.Cells(i, 24)
                     ws.Cells(i, 27) = ws.Cells(i, 1) * ws.Cells(i, 24) * 2.20462 & " lbs"
                     j = j + 1
                Else
                    For k = UBound(WArray) To j
                        ReDim Preserve WArray(k)
                            WArray(k) = ws.Cells(i, 1) * ws.Cells(24)
                            ws.Cells(i, 27) = ws.Cells(i, 1) * ws.Cells(i, 24) * 2.020462 & " lbs"

                    Next k
                    j = j + 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
    If ButtonType = "kg" And ws.Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
        GoTo SumTotals
    End If

    Next i

SumTotals:
        TotalWeight = 0
        For i = 1 To UBound(WArray)
            TotalWeight = WorksheetFunction.Round(TotalWeight + WArray(i), 3)
            Debug.Print TotalWeight
        Next i

        If ButtonType = "kg" Then
            ws.Cells(60, 8) = TotalWeight & " kg"
        End If
        If ButtonType = "lbs" Then
            ws.Cells(60, 8) = TotalWeight & " lbs"
        End If
End Function
```

Loop goes to first page `i = 26 to 51` goes through and compares the `ButtonType` (there are two buttons on the worksheet that trigger this function), does the math puts the value of the product into the array and also puts it into the 'Total Weight' Column (`ws.cells(i,27)`) with the proper description(kg or lbs)

Comment: `TotalWeight As Integer` this only allows integers, no decimal places.  declare it as a double `TotalWeight As Double`

Comment: Damn it! I literally spend 20 minutes trying different iterations of this, you're correct `Dim TotalWeight as Double` is the right answer. Thanks Scott.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Scott Craner,

`Dim TotalWeight as Double` is the correct answer.